# My filename is not persisted in my database with Vichuploader

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I tried to upload images in my database with Symfony 5 and Vichuploader bundle but my filename is not persisted in my database and I don't know why.

This the error that I have : **An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'filename' cannot be null**

This is my entity Person.php :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PersonRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PersonRepository::class)
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Movie::class, mappedBy="writers")
     */
    public $writedMovies;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Movie::class, mappedBy="directors")
     */
    private $directedMovies;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Movie::class, mappedBy="producers")
     */
    private $producedMovies;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MovieActor::class, mappedBy="person", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $movieActors;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $sex;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deathDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $middleName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $biography;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=MovieMusicComposer::class, mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $movieMusicComposers;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=AwardPerson::class, mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $awardPeople;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award3;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award4;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award5;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $award6;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nationality;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PicturePerson::class, mappedBy="person", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $picturePeople;

    /**
     * @Assert\All({
     *   @Assert\Image(mimeTypes="image/jpeg")
     * })
     */
    private $pictureFiles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated_at;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->writedMovies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->movieActors = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->movieMusicComposers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->awardPeoples = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->directedMovies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->producedMovies = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->awardPeople = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->picturePeople = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    public function setBirthDate(\DateTimeInterface $birthDate): self
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Movie[]
     */
    public function getWritedMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->writedMovies;
    }

    public function addWritedMovie(Movie $writedMovie): self
    {
        if (!$this->writedMovies->contains($writedMovie)) {
            $this->writedMovies[] = $writedMovie;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeWritedMovie(Movie $writedMovie): self
    {
        $this->writedMovies->removeElement($writedMovie);

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return Collection|MovieActor[]
     */
    public function getMovieActors(): Collection
    {
        return $this->movieActors;
    }

    public function addMovieActor(MovieActor $movieActor): self
    {
        if (!$this->movieActors->contains($movieActor)) {
            $this->movieActors[] = $movieActor;
            $movieActor->setPerson($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMovieActor(MovieActor $movieActor): self
    {
        if ($this->movieActors->removeElement($movieActor)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($movieActor->getPerson() === $this) {
                $movieActor->setPerson(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSex(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->sex;
    }

    public function setSex(bool $sex): self
    {
        $this->sex = $sex;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPseudo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->pseudo;
    }

    public function setPseudo(?string $pseudo): self
    {
        $this->pseudo = $pseudo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeathDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deathDate;
    }

    public function setDeathDate(?\DateTimeInterface $deathDate): self
    {
        $this->deathDate = $deathDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(?string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMiddleName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->middleName;
    }

    public function setMiddleName(string $middleName): self
    {
        $this->middleName = $middleName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBiography(): ?string
    {
        return $this->biography;
    }

    public function setBiography(?string $biography): self
    {
        $this->biography = $biography;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|MovieMusicComposer[]
     */
    public function getMovieMusicComposers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->movieMusicComposers;
    }

    public function addMovieMusicComposer(MovieMusicComposer $movieMusicComposer): self
    {
        if (!$this->movieMusicComposers->contains($movieMusicComposer)) {
            $this->movieMusicComposers[] = $movieMusicComposer;
            $movieMusicComposer->setPerson($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMovieMusicComposer(MovieMusicComposer $movieMusicComposer): self
    {
        if ($this->movieMusicComposers->removeElement($movieMusicComposer)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($movieMusicComposer->getPerson() === $this) {
                $movieMusicComposer->setPerson(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Movie[]
     */
    public function getDirectedMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->directedMovies;
    }

    public function addDirectedMovie(Movie $directedMovie): self
    {
        if (!$this->directedMovies->contains($directedMovie)) {
            $this->directedMovies[] = $directedMovie;
            $directedMovie->addDirector($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDirectedMovie(Movie $directedMovie): self
    {
        if ($this->directedMovies->removeElement($directedMovie)) {
            $directedMovie->removeDirector($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Movie[]
     */
    public function getProducedMovies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->producedMovies;
    }

    public function addProducedMovie(Movie $producedMovie): self
    {
        if (!$this->producedMovies->contains($producedMovie)) {
            $this->producedMovies[] = $producedMovie;
            $producedMovie->addProducer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProducedMovie(Movie $producedMovie): self
    {
        if ($this->producedMovies->removeElement($producedMovie)) {
            $producedMovie->removeProducer($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|AwardPerson[]
     */
    public function getAwardPeople(): Collection
    {
        return $this->awardPeople;
    }

    public function addAwardPerson(AwardPerson $awardPerson): self
    {
        if (!$this->awardPeople->contains($awardPerson)) {
            $this->awardPeople[] = $awardPerson;
            $awardPerson->setPerson($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAwardPerson(AwardPerson $awardPerson): self
    {
        if ($this->awardPeople->removeElement($awardPerson)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($awardPerson->getPerson() === $this) {
                $awardPerson->setPerson(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award1;
    }

    public function setAward1(?string $award1): self
    {
        $this->award1 = $award1;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award2;
    }

    public function setAward2(?string $award2): self
    {
        $this->award2 = $award2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward3(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award3;
    }

    public function setAward3(?string $award3): self
    {
        $this->award3 = $award3;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward4(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award4;
    }

    public function setAward4(?string $award4): self
    {
        $this->award4 = $award4;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward5(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award5;
    }

    public function setAward5(?string $award5): self
    {
        $this->award5 = $award5;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAward6(): ?string
    {
        return $this->award6;
    }

    public function setAward6(?string $award6): self
    {
        $this->award6 = $award6;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNationality(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nationality;
    }

    public function setNationality(?string $nationality): self
    {
        $this->nationality = $nationality;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|PicturePerson[]
     */
    public function getPicturePeople(): Collection
    {
        return $this->picturePeople;
    }

    public function addPicturePerson(PicturePerson $picturePerson): self
    {
        if (!$this->picturePeople->contains($picturePerson)) {
            $this->picturePeople[] = $picturePerson;
            $picturePerson->setPerson($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

     /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPictureFiles()
    {
        return $this->pictureFiles;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $pictureFiles
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setPictureFiles($pictureFiles): self
    {
        foreach($pictureFiles as $pictureFile) {
            $picture = new PicturePerson();
            $picture->setImageFile($pictureFile);
            $this->addPicturePerson($picture);
        }
        $this->pictureFiles = $pictureFiles;
        return $this;
    }

    public function removePicturePerson(PicturePerson $picturePerson): self
    {
        if ($this->picturePeople->removeElement($picturePerson)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($picturePerson->getPerson() === $this) {
                $picturePerson->setPerson(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $created_at): self
    {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my Entity PicturePerson.php :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PicturePersonRepository::class)
 */
class PicturePerson
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var File|null
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     mimeTypes="image/jpeg"
     * )
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="person_image", fileNameProperty="filename")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person::class, inversedBy="picturePeople")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $person;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFilename(): ?string
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    public function setFilename(?string $filename): self
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPerson(): ?Person
    {
        return $this->person;
    }

    public function setPerson(?Person $person): self
    {
        $this->person = $person;

        return $this;
    }

     /**
     * @return null|File
     */
    public function getImageFile(): ?File
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param null|File $imageFile
     * @return self
     */
    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile): self
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is my config file vich_uploader.yaml :

```
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        movie_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/movies
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/movies'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
        movie_video:
            uri_prefix: /videos/movies
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/videos/movies'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
        movie_audio:
            uri_prefix: /audios/movies
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/audios/movies'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
        person_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/person_image
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/person_image'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\UniqidNamer
```

This is my form PersonType.php:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Person;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('pseudo', TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Pseudonyme",
                "required" => false
            ])
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Nom",
                "required" => true
            ])
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, [
                "label" => "Prénom",
                "required" => true
            ])
            ->add('middleName', TextType::class, [
                "label" => "2ème Prénom",
                "required" => false
            ])
            ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class, [
                "widget" => "single_text",
                "label" => "Date de naissance",
            ])
            ->add('deathDate', BirthdayType::class, [
                "widget" => "single_text",
                "label" => "Date de mort",
                "required" => false
            ])
            ->add('sex', ChoiceType::class, [
                "label" => "Genre",
                'choices'  => [
                    'Homme' => true,
                    'Femme' => false,
                ],
            ]) 
            ->add('nationality', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Nationalité"
            ])
            ->add('award1', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 1"
            ])
            ->add('award2', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 2"
            ])
            ->add('award3', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 3"
            ])
            ->add('award4', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 4"
            ])
            ->add('award5', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 5"
            ])
            ->add('award6', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Récompense 6"
            ])
            ->add('pictureFiles', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true, 
                'label' => 'Chargement d\'images (jpeg uniquement) '
            ])
            ->add('biography', TextareaType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                "label" => "Biographie",
            ])
            // ->add('awardPeople', TextType::class, [
            //     "label" => "Prix remporté(s)"
            // ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Person::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you kindly strip your code from all non-relevant attributes and other stuff? would be so much easier to read.

Comment: Replace FileType with VichImageType